# Find bootloader

Tags: linux, boot-loader

Out of curiosity, is it possible to find out which bootloader was used to start a given system? Was the system booted by [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), [LILO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_(bootloader)) or any other boot loader?

I guess there must exist some `/sys` or `/proc` variable for the same?

EDIT:

> Boot Info Summary:  => Lilo is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda
>
> sda1: ___________________________________________________________________
>
> ```
> File system:       
> Boot sector type:  Unknown
> Boot sector info:
> Mounting failed: mount: unknown filesystem type ''
> ```

`/dev/sda` is the only device I have to boot with.

I wonder, if there is no known file system on the only available single partition, then how did it manage to boot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this info is tracked in meaningful way under either `/sys` or `/proc`. About the only way I can fathom this would be accessible to you after a boot is by interrogating the system either by looking to see if a GRUB or Lilo configuration file was present, or by making use of a script such as [`bootinfoscript`](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/).

#### Example - check boot device

If you know which device your system was booted with you can use `dd` to dump the contents of the boot loader and then `grep` for either GRUB or LILO.

[image: ss #1]

You can use these commands to determine whether you're using GRUB or LILO:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep GRUB
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep LILO
```

Which ever returns this string is the boot loader you're using:

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

#### Example - using bootinfoscript

```
$ sudo ./bootinfoscript --stdout
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
    location.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub2/grub.cfg
    ...
```

Neither of these approaches is "conclusive", however, since multiple boot loaders can coexist, but at least it gives you a rough idea of the boot loaders that "might" be in use.

#### References

- [How do I find out which boot loader I have?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24459/how-do-i-find-out-which-boot-loader-i-have)

Comment: Worth pointing out how useful `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | strings` might be over just grepping here as you'll get some info no matter what you're running.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This script is written in Bash, however, so if you need to run it on an embedded platform you will have to modify it. I have tested this script and it has correctly recognized GRUB on Ubuntu and LILO on Slackware.

Answer (score 2):

To get bootloader id use [bootloader_type](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0adb32858b0bddf4ada5f364a84ed60b196dbcda/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt#L140)

```
echo $((`cat /proc/sys/kernel/bootloader_type`>>4))
```

Find your [bootloader id](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0adb32858b0bddf4ada5f364a84ed60b196dbcda/Documentation/x86/boot.txt#L374)