# Is UEFI a bootloader as well as a replacement of BIOS?

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, boot-loader

Does this laptop with Lubuntu 18.04  have a bootloader installed and use it? If not, what does it use instead? What is its booting process like?

Does the laptop use UEFI instead of BIOS?
Is UEFI a bootloader besides a replacement of BIOS?

I follow https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137587/674 to find out bootloader.

Thanks.

```
$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for t: 
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB  ext4

$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep GRUB
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep LILO
$ sudo ./bootinfoscript --stdout
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   976,773,167   976,773,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,050,624   976,771,071   975,720,448 Data partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        0C1E-EE69                              vfat       
/dev/sda2        7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda2        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)


=========================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic root=UUID=7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-45-generic-advanced-7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-45-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic root=UUID=7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-45-generic-recovery-7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-45-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic root=UUID=7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-45-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-advanced-7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-recovery-7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda2/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=7a7ed7ca-d939-49d6-8951-ba573929f41f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0C1E-EE69  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-7fBr4xK8/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It clearly says `EFI System Partition` so I guess it uses EFI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface as (most?) today's x86 computers.

Comment: Which laptop (What do you mean by “this”)?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking about the firmware of the laptop, now I see you are asking about what is installed on the hard-disk. I have edited you question, to prevent others making the same mistake.

Comment: “Is the bootloader, that is installed on this laptop, used?”

Comment: Ah yes, the very question I thought you were asking at the start. However I don't now know if you are asking because you don't know, or as a snide comment about my comment. Out.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  EFI is replacement of BIOS. Is it also a bootloader, replacing GRUB?

Comment: Answer is very simple, no. The key point is you need to understand how OS boot, on x86, from the very beginning -- you plug on power.

Comment: @炸 Thanks. Could you elaborate in an answer maybe? Does UEFL contain a bootloader within itself, so it doesn't need GRUB?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that laptop has an UEFI version of the GRUB bootloader installed - you can see the `/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` file. But there is no **MBR-style** bootloader installed, as evidenced by the output

```
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda
```

No, UEFI is not technically a bootloader.

UEFI is a *system firmware*, and replaces BIOS in that role on modern PCs. A bootloader could be defined as "something relatively simple (compared to an actual OS), that utilizes the services provided by the system firmware to load the actual operating system."

The system firmware initially controls the system, and so it will dictate *what a bootloader is expected to be like*. A traditional PC BIOS would essentially:

- setup the system in 16-bit 8086-compatible mode
- read the first 512-byte block of a disk that has been previously selected in some not-so-well-specified way
- if the two last bytes of that block are 0x55 and 0xaa, then attempt to execute the first 446 or so bytes of the block as a program. Provide it the basic input/output functions, callable essentially same way as in the original IBM PC/AT in year 1986, with a number of various extensions added in here and there over the years.

On a modern system, 446 bytes is barely enough to cover the possible disk access interfaces (old C/H/S and the modern LBA), and then load the rest of the bootloader, which is often embedded in the space between the Master Boot Record and the beginning of the first partition.

UEFI on the other hand will:

- allow the use of the system's native bit depth, whether 32- or 64-bit.
- provide a built-in support for reading at least (a specific version of) a FAT32 filesystem on a GPT partition. Other filesystems may be supported too.
- provide a standard interface for the bootloader and the OS to access firmware settings, including the boot order settings
- allow the bootloader to be *a regular file*, not a fixed-size block of machine code in a specific location.

If you use the `sudo efibootmgr -v` command, you'll see the link between the system firmware and the bootloader: the UEFI boot order settings. They are stored in the battery-backed NVRAM memory of the system (= essentially the same place the BIOS settings were stored on systems that had BIOS instead of UEFI), and specify four things about each configured bootloader:

- its human-readable name
- the GUID-style partition ID of the partition containing the bootloader
- the filename of the bootloader, usually with DOS/Windows-style backslashes as directory separators
- a string of additional parameters each bootloader can decide how to use.

In your case, the bootloader registered in the UEFI boot order might not actually be `/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`, but `/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`: the UEFI Secure Boot shim bootloader. It is signed by Microsoft and so should be loadable on essentially all 64-bit x86 systems supporting UEFI Secure Boot. It has a built-in copy of Canonical's Secure Boot certificate, and it uses that (or optionally any other certificate installed into the system NVRAM as Machine Owner Key, or MOK) to cryptographically verify the next file it loads, which is by convention the `grubx64.efi` file in the same directory the `shimx64.efi` is located in.

If your system doesn't have Secure Boot enabled, this step can be skipped and `\efi\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` might be specified directly in the UEFI boot order settings.

For removable media and other situations where the bootloader might not be registered in NVRAM settings, UEFI also includes a fallback bootloader path. For 64-bit x86 architecture, it's `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi`. If this file exists in a FAT32 partition on a removable media, then that media is effectively **bootable** for UEFI.

It would be technically possible (and in fact quite easy) to embed a UEFI-compatible bootloader into the system firmware. But that makes it hard to update the bootloader, which can often be specific to a particular OS or a family of OSs. As a result, you'd be generally more likely to see such an embedded bootloader in *an appliance* rather than in *a general-purpose computer*.

Comment: It is also possible to skip GRUB, the kernel itself can be configured as an EFI bootloader.

Comment: I tend to just point people to http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html so they could get even better description with less effort :-)

Comment: @StephenKitt "the kernel itself can be configured as an EFI bootloader". Do you mean an OS kernel can be a bootloader of itself or a bootloader of firmware EFI?

Comment: The Linux kernel can boot itself from EFI: you can copy a kernel to the ESP, and boot it directly from EFI, without GRUB or anything else.

Comment: @StephenKitt is "the Linux kernel can boot itself from EFI" a popular or better practice than using a boot loader?

Comment: I think GRUB is used more often than directly booting the kernel. I think it’s better to use GRUB, if only because it makes it easier to recover from mistakes.

Comment: How many stages are there in the bootloading stages in UEFI? I am trying to picture a diagram  for the bootloading stages in UEFI, similar to the diagram of bootloading stages in BIOS in https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/GNU_GRUB_components.svg?

Comment: When GRUB is booting in UEFI native style, there are no separate `boot.img` + `core.img`; the `\efi\<distribution name>\grubx64.efi` includes the equivalent of both of those. It is also possible (but optional) to include any number of GRUB modules from `/boot/grub/` into the `grubx64.efi` file, making it a fully self-contained executable, which can make things easier with Secure Boot. So two stages: first `grubx64.efi`in EFI system partition, then directly to `/boot/grub/`, with an asterisk indicating that the second stage can be eliminated if necessary.